# Change characters in CSV filne - CHR(13)

Tags: shell, csv, character-encoding, character

I have problem with loading file into database. The problem is that some Cell(strings) contains of CHR(13) - carriage return. I am loading files using Sql loader, but if row contains string with CHR(13 )it's getting messy and script recognize that CHR(13) is end of row(instead of end of string), so in result i have 25 rows from file that contains 20 rows.

I want to change CHR(13) to CHR(32) - space, but i don't know how to do it. If i changed all CHR(13) to CHR(32) i will delated all lines(so my file will contain only 1 line). How can i do it smart? I want to delete only additional CHR(13).

Example how my file looks like:

```
"Title 1","Title 2","Title 3","Title 4"
"Value 1",,"Value 3","Value 4"
"Value 1",""Value 2","Value 3","Value 4"
"Value 1,""Value
asfsafsaf","Value 3,"Value 4" <--- There is problem
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed, you can do it like this:

```
sed -zr 's/([^"])[\n\r]+/\1 /g' yourfile > yourmodified_file
```

I am not 100% sure what your line ending convention is, maybe you have to try one of these instead of the `[\n\r]+` part :

- `\r`
- `\n`

The script replaces seqences of cariage return and/or linefeed, that are **not** preceded by a double quote (that is the `[^"]` part), with a space.

Comment: I had changed all values in CELL from \n to \r and now its working perfect :) I have used python for this purpose